# What is the alternative to `<?php the_content(); ?>` when it comes to calling Media (image) files in the 'attachment.php' file?

Tags: php, uploads, media, media-library, images

I am in the process of putting together my own WordPress Theme.  Up until now, I have been using the 'single.php' file to act as a Template for both my Blogs and Media Files.  In reference to my Media files, I have been using the `<?php the_content(); ?>` tag to call such images.

I have now reached the stage, where I have created an 'attachment.php' file for the various Media files.  I have noticed that the `<?php the_content(); ?>` does not work in said file, unlike in the 'single.php' file.

What is the relevant alternative to `<?php the_content(); ?>` when it comes to calling images in the 'attachment.php' file?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `the_content` from within attachment.php will bring you the Attachment Description.

Put the code below on your page and see what you can get from within attachment.php file:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    /**
     * @link    https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata#Related
     */
    $data = array(
        get_the_ID(), // Gets att ID.
        get_permalink(), // Gets att page link.
        get_the_title(), // Gets att title.
        get_the_content(), // Gets att description.
        wp_get_attachment_metadata(), // Gets att metadata.
    );

    var_dump( $data );

endwhile;
```

Also, you might want to take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata#Related and see other functions that will perhaps be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately, your code produces a long message starting with `array(5) { [0]=> int(237) [1]=> string(39) "http://www.example.com/leather-brown/" [2]=> string(13) "Leather Brown" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> array(5)`.  How could I resolve this?  Thanks for the additional link, also.

Comment: You said you wanted to bring the image within your template. So by calling var_dump in the above case you should have seen the image source for the media attachment. Now you just do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain fully.  I want to be able to upload an image via the WordPress Dashboard and then able to view that image within its own URL.  I can call it via the 'single.php' file but the tag does not work within the 'attachment.php' file.

Comment: Did you access the link I sent you in my answer? Did you see the image source link? Did you try calling the function wp_get_attachment_image()?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
<?php if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post->id ) ) : $att_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->id, "full"); ?>

<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->id); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="attachment">
<img src="<?php echo $att_image[0];?>" width="<?php echo $att_image[1];?>" height="<?php echo $att_image[2];?>" alt="" />
</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Use it inside the loop. Above example first checks if the attachment is an image.

Or you might also want to just use wp_get_attachment_image() to output the entire image tag:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

There's also get_atached_media that you can use.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media